# How to use the LeafletJS polylineDecorator plugin with a GeoJSON featureCollection?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to use the polylinedecorator leaflet plugin but can't seem to get it to work with my GeoJSON featureCollection and display on my map.

Here's my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/5x9hx5x2/1/) . *Note: I pasted the polylinedecorator plugin code in the Javascript section. Scroll to the bottom of the fiddle to see my actual code.*

> Here's my actual code:

```
var data = {

  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            13.974609375,
            31.728167146023935
          ],
          [
            12.83203125,
            34.74161249883172
          ],
          [
            14.501953124999998,
            35.31736632923788
          ],
          [
            16.5234375,
            37.16031654673677
          ],
          [
            17.841796875,
            38.41055825094609
          ],
          [
            16.611328125,
            40.245991504199026
          ],
          [
            19.072265625,
            43.389081939117496
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            19.51171875,
            30.90222470517144
          ],
          [
            19.072265625,
            33.65120829920497
          ],
          [
            20.830078125,
            35.24561909420681
          ],
          [
            21.26953125,
            38.47939467327645
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            24.521484375,
            32.10118973232094
          ],
          [
            26.54296875,
            35.96022296929667
          ],
          [
            25.13671875,
            36.80928470205937
          ],
          [
            23.466796875,
            38.13455657705411
          ],
          [
            24.960937499999996,
            41.31082388091818
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

var polylines = L.geoJson(polylines, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        L.polylineDecorator(layer, {
            patterns: [
                {offset: 25, repeat: 30, symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 15, pathOptions: {fillOpacity: 1, weight: 0}})}
            ]
        })
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remember that `L.polylineDecorator(...)` returns an instance of the decorator layers *that you must add to the map*, i.e.:

```
var polylines = L.geoJson(json, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    L.polylineDecorator(layer, {
      patterns: [
        {offset: 25, repeat: 30, symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 15, pathOptions: {fillOpacity: 1, weight: 0}})}
      ]
    }).addTo(map);  /// Adds each decorator to the map!!!!
  } 
}).addTo(map);
```

Simply instantiating the polyline decorator does *not* add it to the map. You can, of course, store the decorators in a variable and add them later, or use a `L.Control.Layers` to toggle them on and off, etc.

See it working at https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/dey/1/edit?html,output

That example adds the decorators directly to the map. If you want to add them to the `L.GeoJSON` instance instead, use `addTo(this)`. Or add them to a different `L.LayerGroup` and add the group to the map, etc etc etc.

Comment: That worked. Thanks, I had to add it to a L.layerGroup like you said.

Comment: This solution will work, however if I'm adding the polylineDecorator to the "map" object, and later I'm toggling the entire geoJson Data, the arrow head will not disappear (Although the data layer itself will disappear). So how can I toggle the arrow-head with the entire data-layer????

Comment: @GilEpshtain, do not ask questions in comments.